# iOS SDK Facebook Seamless Permissions Screens

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing an iOS app that requires login, read and post/publish permissions upfront.

I am using iOS FB SDK's Login Manager class. I can get all these permissions just fine.

My problem is after user grants the first permission, my app's screen is shown momentarily before it gets directed to second permission screen and so on.

How can i change this behavior so that user feels that he never came out of Facebook after granting each of these permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.